# Python: how to get a dict key given its value without looping?

Tags: python, dictionary

so I have a dict with values: [Assuming No Duplicates]

```
mydict={0: 1, 1: 2, -2: -1, -1: 0, -3: -2}
```

and what I want to is do is get they key using the value, so if 1 is given I want it to get they key who has value 1, which is 0 and append it to the list.

```
 finalO=[]
  if x in myddict.values():
      finalO.append([mydict.**getKeyByVal**(x)])--> so is there's a built in function that will allow me to do that?
```

I don't want to make a for loop because I'm trying to do it in linear time.

Comment: What should be returned if there is more than one key with the same value?

Comment: @sayse I forgot to add in my description that there will be no duplicates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's guaranteed that your values are unique, you can create a reversed version of your `dict` where keys and values are switched:

```
mydict = {0: 1, 1: 2, -2: -1, -1: 0, -3: -2}

my_inverted_dict = dict(map(reversed, mydict.items()))

print(my_inverted_dict)
print(my_inverted_dict[1])
```

Output:

```
{1: 0, 2: 1, -1: -2, 0: -1, -2: -3}
0
```

Comment: https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58123757.shtml

Answer (score 2):

You *will* have to loop for this, since you have to invert the mapping of the dictionary. In order to do so you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {j:i for i,j in mydict.items()}
print(d[1])
# 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mydict={0: 1, 1: 2, -2: -1, -1: 0, -3: -2}

search_value = 1

# List comprehension to return items if they match a search value
# This populates a list automatically
final0 = [k for k, v in mydict.items() if v == search_value]

# Note: If you have a value that is paired with more than one key
# then you might want to use set() and iterate through that to ensure
# your values aren't duplicates.

mydict2 = {0: 1, 1: 2, -2: -1, -1: 0, -3: -2, 4: 1} # Added matching value at end
final0 = [i for i in set([k for k, v in mydict.items() if v == search_value])]
```

Comment: You might want to add some comments along with the code to make it clearer for OP

Comment: @yatu Good idea. Updated!  I didn't really bring anything new to the table, but using a dictionary might not be the best choice for OP.  We'd need more context to figure that out.